# Version number not supported by gl2 in andengine

Tags: opengl, android, andengine, opengl-es2

I am new to andengine. From various forums, i got to know that my system should support hardware virtulisation. I have installed "Intel X86" and my system didn't throw any problem regarding "HAX" now. But now i am getting error in logcat as follows

```
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 83
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): org.andengine.opengl.shader.exception.ShaderProgramCompileException: Reason: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  Version number not supported by GL2
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): Source:
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): ##########################
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): uniform mat4 u_modelViewProjectionMatrix;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): attribute vec4 a_position;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): attribute vec2 a_textureCoordinates;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): varying vec2 v_textureCoordinates;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): void main() {
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     v_textureCoordinates = a_textureCoordinates;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     gl_Position = u_modelViewProjectionMatrix * a_position;
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): }
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509): ##########################
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgram.compileShader(ShaderProgram.java:187)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgram.compile(ShaderProgram.java:143)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.ShaderProgram.bind(ShaderProgram.java:122)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.shader.PositionTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.bind(PositionTextureCoordinatesShaderProgram.java:86)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.vbo.VertexBufferObject.bind(VertexBufferObject.java:162)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureWarmUpVertexBufferObject.warmup(TextureWarmUpVertexBufferObject.java:97)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:257)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1462)
09-13 22:20:43.195: E/AndroidRuntime(1509):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
09-13 22:20:43.275: E/OpenGLRenderer(1509): Error while compiling shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  Version number not supported by GL2
09-13 22:20:43.304: E/OpenGLRenderer(1509): Error while compiling shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  Version number not supported by GL2
```

I am getting similar kind of error when i tried to execute my program in BlueStacks and my application gets crashed. Pls help me regarding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you put a `#version` tag in your GLSL source?  You should have something like `#version 100` at the top of the file, or whichever version number is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Hi, My opengl is a built in java language (from andengine) and i am not able to figure it about the GLSL source in it. What can i do? Pls help me

Answer (score -1):

At last I was answered by an expert. The problem was that my emulator/bluestack device didn't support OpenGL ES version 2.0. I downloaded Andengine GL ES 1 and now it works.